# Passing function pointers from Fortran to C, reverse of c_f_procpointer

Tags: c, fortran, function-pointers

I'm trying to use dynamic library loading in Linux with Fortran based on [this](http://cims.nyu.edu/~donev/Fortran/DLL/DLL.Forum.txt), but I'd like to add support for `dladdr`. Basically my code is:

```
procedure(proto), pointer :: my_func
type(c_funptr) :: funptr

funptr = dlsym(handle,'myfunction')
if (c_associated(funptr)) then
  call c_f_procpointer(funptr, my_func)
else
  my_func => myfunction
end if

write(6,*) dladdr(???,info)
```

Many details are missing, but the important part is I want to pass to `dladdr` the actual function represented by `my_func`, which is a procedure pointer to some other function: either something found by `dlsym` or an explicit Fortran association. So my problem is I don't know what to put in the `???`.

I get success (non-zero return value) if I use `funptr` or `c_funloc(myfunction)`, so at least the `dladdr` call is working. But I can't use `my_func` (the gfortran compiler complains about bad argument type), and both `c_loc(my_func)` and `c_funloc(my_func)` fail (zero return value). I think the problem is I have to "dereference" `my_func` once, and then get the C function pointer that. How could I do that?

Full code:

**dlfcn.f90**

```
MODULE DLFCN
   USE ISO_C_BINDING
   IMPLICIT NONE
   PRIVATE
   PUBLIC :: DLOpen, DLSym, DLClose, DLError, DLAddr ! DL API

   ! Valid modes for mode in DLOpen:
   INTEGER, PARAMETER, PUBLIC :: RTLD_LAZY=1, RTLD_NOW=2, RTLD_GLOBAL=256, RTLD_LOCAL=0
      ! Obtained from the output of the previously listed C program

   INTERFACE ! All we need is interfaces for the prototypes in <dlfcn.h>
      FUNCTION DLOpen(file,mode) RESULT(handle) BIND(C,NAME="dlopen")
         ! void *dlopen(const char *file, int mode);
         USE ISO_C_BINDING
         CHARACTER(C_CHAR), DIMENSION(*), INTENT(IN) :: file
            ! C strings should be declared as character arrays
         INTEGER(C_INT), VALUE :: mode
         TYPE(C_PTR) :: handle
      END FUNCTION
      FUNCTION DLSym(handle,name) RESULT(funptr) BIND(C,NAME="dlsym")
         ! void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *name);
         USE ISO_C_BINDING
         TYPE(C_PTR), VALUE :: handle
         CHARACTER(C_CHAR), DIMENSION(*), INTENT(IN) :: name
         TYPE(C_FUNPTR) :: funptr ! A function pointer
      END FUNCTION
      FUNCTION DLClose(handle) RESULT(status) BIND(C,NAME="dlclose")
         ! int dlclose(void *handle);
         USE ISO_C_BINDING
         TYPE(C_PTR), VALUE :: handle
         INTEGER(C_INT) :: status
      END FUNCTION
      FUNCTION DLError() RESULT(error) BIND(C,NAME="dlerror")
         ! char *dlerror(void);
         USE ISO_C_BINDING
         TYPE(C_PTR) :: error
      END FUNCTION
      ! dladdr is a Glibc extension, not POSIX
      FUNCTION DLAddr(funptr,info) RESULT(output) BIND(C,NAME="dladdr")
         ! int dladdr(void *addr, Dl_info *info)
         USE ISO_C_BINDING
         TYPE(C_FUNPTR) :: funptr ! A function pointer
         TYPE(C_PTR) :: info
         INTEGER(C_INT) :: output
      END FUNCTION
   END INTERFACE

END MODULE
```

**test.f90**

```
program test
use iso_c_binding
use dlfcn
implicit none
abstract interface
  function proto(s,i)
    character(len=*) :: s
    integer :: i
    integer :: proto
  end function proto
end interface

procedure(proto), pointer :: my_func
character(kind=c_char,len=1024) :: libname,funname
type(c_ptr) :: handle=c_null_ptr
type(c_funptr) :: funptr=c_null_funptr
type(c_ptr) :: info

libname = 'libblas.so'
funname = 'xerbla_'
handle = dlopen(trim(libname)//c_null_char, int(ior(rtld_global,rtld_lazy),kind=c_int))
if (c_associated(handle)) then
  write (6,*) trim(libname),' loaded'
else
  write(6,*) 'error loading '//trim(libname)
end if
funptr = dlsym(handle,trim(funname)//c_null_char)
if (c_associated(funptr)) then
  call c_f_procpointer(funptr, my_func)
else
  my_func => myfunction
end if

write(6,*) dladdr(funptr,info)
write(6,*) dladdr(c_funloc(myfunction),info)
write(6,*) dladdr(c_funloc(my_func),info)
!write(6,*) dladdr(my_func,info)

contains

function myfunction(srname,info)
  character(len=*) :: srname
  integer :: info
  integer :: myfunction
  myfunction = 0
end function myfunction

end program test
```

Compile with:

```
gfortran dlfcn.f90 test.f90 -ldl -o test
```

Run:

```
$ ./test 
 libblas.so loaded
           1
           1
           0
```

If I enable the commented-out line, the compiler says:

```
write(6,*) dladdr(my_func,info)
                  1
Error: Invalid procedure argument at (1)
```

which makes sense, because `my_func` is a Fortran procedure pointer, not a C pointer, as `dladdr` expects.

Comment: How does the compiler complain? How do `myfunction` and `proto` look like? Your question is quite incomplete.

Comment: @VladimirF I didn't think the missing details are significant, but I've now posted a full sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface for DLAddr in the Fortran source does not match the documented interface of the corresponding C function.  The VALUE attribute is required on both arguments.

It is also worth noting that the argument to C_FUNLOC (which is what you need in the ???) needs to be an interoperable procedure, i.e. one that has the BIND attribute.  This attribute is missing from the interface used in the procedure pointer declaration in the Fortran code (and also from `my_function`, if you want that to have the same characteristics).

Comment: I must have been blind, why didn't I see the `VALUE` attribute in the other functions? Once that's fixed, and I make sure the `info` pointer is associated too, it seems to be working even without the `BIND(C)` attribute, at least for this simple case.

Comment: But put the BIND(C) in.  Studies have conclusively shown that you will sleep better at night, earn a higher salary and have many more friends with it there.